# observeSingleEvent returns nil - swift 3

Tags: ios, json, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with firebase and swift. I tried to use the `function: observeSingleEvent`.
I have objects in the database and I have checked the documentation and seen a lot of tutorials. But no matter what I do the function returns "nil" or returns an error :(

```
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Event")

   let eventID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
   ref.child("Event").child(eventID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
       let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
       let postDict = value?["title"] as? String ?? ""

       print(snapshot)
       print(postDict)
   })
```

Comment: If your first block is triggered with an empty snapshot, it means that there is no value at the location that you're observing. If you get an error: share that error.

Comment: the wird thing is that if i chech if there is objects in the firebase, with this code:
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Event")

refHandle = ref.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in      
let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]      

     print(snapshot)
     print(postDict)

     it returns all the objects i have in the firebase database